# Question about tabling and declaring functions in main

Tags: c++

the problem is in the int main()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
const int R = 15;
const int C = 20;
void clearArray(int arr[R][C])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < C; j++)
    {
      arr[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
}
void makeSpiral(int arr[R][C],int r , int c)
{
  int i, a = 0, b = 0;
  int value = 1;
  while (a < r && b < c)
  {
    for (i = a; i < r; ++i)
    {
      arr[i][b] = value++;
    }
    b++;
    for (i = b; i < c; ++i)
    {
      arr[r - 1][i] = value++;
    }
    r--;
    if (a < r)
    {
      for (i = r - 1; i >= a; --i)
      {
        arr[i][c-1] = value++;
      }
      c--;
    }
    if (b < c)
    {
      for (i = c - 1; i >= b; --i)
      {
        arr[a][i] = value++;
      }
      a++;
    }
  }
}
void printSpiral(int arr[R][C],int r , int c, char str[])
{
  str[30];
  ofstream fout;
  fout.open(str, ios::out | ios::app);
  if (!fout)
  {
    cout << "Error: file could not be opened" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  fout << endl;
  fout << "---------------------------------------------";
  for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
  {
    fout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
      fout <<setw(5)<< arr[i][j] << " ";
    }
  }
  fout.close();
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char str[30];
  ofstream fout;
  int r,c;
  int i,j,t;
  int arr[R][C];
  if (argc < 2)
  {
    cout << "Error missing file name!" << endl;
    return -1;
  }
  strcpy(str, argv[1]);
  int matrix [R][C] = {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5},{4,7},{7,4},{15,20}};
  for (i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++)
  {
    clearArray(matrix);
    makeSpiral(matrix,R,C);
    printSpiral (matrix,R,C,str);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I'm a new C++ programmer please go easy on me. So i have this piece of code, the professor requires me to store corner sizes of a spiral matrix into a table, then use a loop to call out my functions so i don't have to call my functions repeatedly like this:

```
clearArray(matrix);
makeSpiral(matrix,1,1);
printSpiral (matrix,1,1,str);


clearArray(matrix);
makeSpiral(matrix,2,2);
printSpiral (matrix,2,2,str);


clearArray(matrix);
makeSpiral(matrix,3,3);
printSpiral (matrix,3,3,str);


clearArray(matrix);
makeSpiral(matrix,4,4);
printSpiral (matrix,4,4,str);
```

I want to print a counter-clockwise matrix 8 times which with corner 1 by 1 ; 2 by 2; 3 by 3; 4 by 4; 5 by 5; 4 by 7; 7 by 4; and 15 by 20.
My code doesn't give me the correct output, can you tell me where I did wrong, thank you!

The output that i supposed to have

```
---------------------------------
    1 
---------------------------------
    1     3 
---------------------------------
    3 
    2 
---------------------------------
    1     4 
    2     3 
---------------------------------
    1     8     7 
    2     9     6 
    3     4     5 
---------------------------------
    1    12    11    10 
    2    13    16     9 
    3    14    15     8 
    4     5     6     7 
---------------------------------
    1    16    15    14    13 
    2    17    24    23    12 
    3    18    25    22    11 
    4    19    20    21    10 
    5     6     7     8     9 
---------------------------------
    1    18    17    16    15    14    13 
    2    19    28    27    26    25    12 
    3    20    21    22    23    24    11 
    4     5     6     7     8     9    10 
---------------------------------
    1    18    17    16 
    2    19    28    15 
    3    20    27    14 
    4    21    26    13 
    5    22    25    12 
    6    23    24    11 
    7     8     9    10 
---------------------------------
    1    20    19    18    17    16    15    14 
    2    21    32    31    30    29    28    13 
    3    22    23    24    25    26    27    12 
    4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11 
---------------------------------
    1    16    15    14 
    2    17    24    13 
    3    18    23    12 
    4    19    22    11 
    5    20    21    10 
    6     7     8     9
```

What my code output looks like:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------
 1 66 65 64 63 62 61 60 59 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51 50 49 48
 2 67 124 123 122 121 120 119 118 117 116 115 114 113 112 111 110 109 108 47
 3 68 125 174 173 172 171 170 169 168 167 166 165 164 163 162 161 160 107 46
 4 69 126 175 216 215 214 213 212 211 210 209 208 207 206 205 204 159 106 45
 5 70 127 176 217 250 249 248 247 246 245 244 243 242 241 240 203 158 105 44
 6 71 128 177 218 251 276 275 274 273 272 271 270 269 268 239 202 157 104 43
 7 72 129 178 219 252 277 294 293 292 291 290 289 288 267 238 201 156 103 42
 8 73 130 179 220 253 278 295 296 297 298 299 300 287 266 237 200 155 102 41
 9 74 131 180 221 254 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 265 236 199 154 101 40
 10 75 132 181 222 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 235 198 153 100 39
 11 76 133 182 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 197 152 99 38
 12 77 134 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 151 98 37
 13 78 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 97 36
 14 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 35
 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
------------------------------------------------------------
 1 66 65 64 63 62 61 60 59 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51 50 49 48
 2 67 124 123 122 121 120 119 118 117 116 115 114 113 112 111 110 109 108 47
 3 68 125 174 173 172 171 170 169 168 167 166 165 164 163 162 161 160 107 46
 4 69 126 175 216 215 214 213 212 211 210 209 208 207 206 205 204 159 106 45
 5 70 127 176 217 250 249 248 247 246 245 244 243 242 241 240 203 158 105 44
 6 71 128 177 218 251 276 275 274 273 272 271 270 269 268 239 202 157 104 43
 7 72 129 178 219 252 277 294 293 292 291 290 289 288 267 238 201 156 103 42
 8 73 130 179 220 253 278 295 296 297 298 299 300 287 266 237 200 155 102 41
 9 74 131 180 221 254 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 265 236 199 154 101 40
 10 75 132 181 222 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 235 198 153 100 39
 11 76 133 182 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 197 152 99 38
 12 77 134 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 151 98 37
 13 78 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 97 36
 14 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 35
 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
---------------------------------------------------------
 1 66 65 64 63 62 61 60 59 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51 50 49 48
 2 67 124 123 122 121 120 119 118 117 116 115 114 113 112 111 110 109 108 47
 3 68 125 174 173 172 171 170 169 168 167 166 165 164 163 162 161 160 107 46
 4 69 126 175 216 215 214 213 212 211 210 209 208 207 206 205 204 159 106 45
 5 70 127 176 217 250 249 248 247 246 245 244 243 242 241 240 203 158 105 44
 6 71 128 177 218 251 276 275 274 273 272 271 270 269 268 239 202 157 104 43
 7 72 129 178 219 252 277 294 293 292 291 290 289 288 267 238 201 156 103 42
 8 73 130 179 220 253 278 295 296 297 298 299 300 287 266 237 200 155 102 41
 9 74 131 180 221 254 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 265 236 199 154 101 40
 10 75 132 181 222 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 235 198 153 100 39
 11 76 133 182 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 197 152 99 38
 12 77 134 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 151 98 37
 13 78 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 97 36
 14 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 35
 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
--------------------------------------------------------
......
It prints the 15x20 corner size 8 times.
```

Comment: Format your code...

Comment: I added the mark-up for code but, please, [edit] your question and remove all these annoying empty lines.

Comment: Thank you, sorry i don't know why it stretched out like that when I pasted it, It wasn't like this on Codeblock.

Comment: You have several prints, yet you only vaguely state your output is wrong. Simplify this. Do one spiral and one print, state your desired output and then the actual one. Also consider helping yourself by printing your matrix after every single assignment, seeing when it goes wrong.

Comment: Also, after the problem is fixed, put your code on CodeReview. There is a lot of things to criticize - essentially you write C styled code. For instance: 1. You should have a class `Spiral` which has what are now functions as methods, 2. the variables in your routines should have more descriptive names than `b`, 3. you shouldn't use raw arrays, except if you really need to optimize, and then only wrapped deep in some class.

Comment: I just started C++ so my professor hasn't gotten to Class yet. But I'll take the criticism thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main function, arguments to `makeSpiral` are fixed `R` and `C`. This means `makeSpiral` always tries to fill a 15 rows, 20 columns spiral matrix to your `matrix`:

> ```c
> makeSpiral(matrix,R,C);
> printSpiral(matrix,R,C,str);
> ```

You may want this instead:

```c
  int matrix[R][C]; // no need of initialization
  int matrixSize[8][2] = {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5},{4,7},{7,4},{15,20}};
  for (i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++) {
    clearArray(matrix, matrixSize[i][0], matrixSize[i][1]);
    makeSpiral(matrix, matrixSize[i][0], matrixSize[i][1]);
    printSpiral (matrix, matrixSize[i][0], matrixSize[i][1], str);
  }
```

Here you use an assist `matrixSize` to store expected matrix sizes. Within the `for` loop `makeSpiral` will fill `matrixSize[i][0]` rows, `matrixSize[i][1]` columns only, so does `printSpiral`.